# MS Access Database .mdb not a valid path

Tags: database, ms-access

I have two .mdb files in 2000 format. One is a user interface and the other one is a database with tables. I copied them from a machine running in windows xp to a machine running in windows 7.I converted them into 2007 format. But, when accessing the interface , am getting an error

".mdb is not a valid path. Make sure the path name is typed correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides".

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you converted them to the 2007 format, the extension changed to .accdb. You'll have to update any linked tables and code that had the old .mdb filename in it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will work on it and come to u sooner.

Comment: .mdb shouldn't exist in your databases at all anymore (provided you're not linking to any pre-Access 2007 format databases). Try to open every linked table through the Access Object bar and make sure they open. Also do a Find in the VBA window for the entire project to see if .mdb is used anywhere.